# object orientation android move method's out of activity into new class with context

Tags: java, android

I have a number of classes that have a logout button, so I thought it would make sense to move the logout method outside each individual class and give it its own class so that I do not have to fix it in more than one place if I make changes to it, however I am facing some problems relating to context

The method takes in a Context context which in this situation would be homeActivity.this

The first problem is

```
                    Util.HideKeyBoard(HomeActivity.this);
```

if I change it to

```
                    Util.HideKeyBoard(context);
```

It is still red and I am not sure why, how do I get around this

The next problem is to start the new activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SignupActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                AnimatorClass.appearLeftAnimation(context);
                finish();
```

StartActivity is red and I am not sure why and the animator class is also red over context, finish is also red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `startActivity()` belongs to the class Context and `finish()` belongs to Activity class.

Check the documentation out:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()

You can solve this like this:

```
public void yourExternalMethod(Activity activity) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SignupActivity.class);
   activity.startActivity(intent);
   AnimatorClass.appearLeftAnimation(activity);
   activity.finish();
}
```

Comment: So is there no way to do this then?